# how to start placement of action buttons from the left in action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am new to android development. Hence, I'm still in the getting-the-hang-of-it mode. I have started off my app by creating an xml file in the res/menu folder, the code for which is shown below. I need help with is placing the first (add) button in the left hand corner, where the title bar is supposed to be located, followed by the remove button in the centre, and finally the overflow menu in the last third. These three entities should be evenly spaced out. Additionally, I have managed to get rid of the app name and icon from the left hand corner.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:id="@+id/setting" 
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never" /> 

<item android:id="@+id/add_contact"
    android:title="@string/action_add"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />


<item android:id="@+id/remove_contact"
    android:title="@string/action_remove"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

This is what I want it to look like. It is a screen shot of the Nexus 4 contacts manager. However, I want buttons not tabs:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TE4hH.png

Current output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPcX6.png

Comment: can you show an image of your desired output/ current output?

Comment: Could you please let us know, if you are facing an issue with current code and what kind of help is required.

Comment: I was able to add buttons to my action bar using the code presented above. The result looks like this:http://i.imgur.com/sQU3Jjq.png
Now, all I need help with is moving the add and remove buttons to the left so that the add button is placed in the left corner, remove in the centre and the overflow menu on the right corner, sort of like the nexus 4 contacts manager screen shot I have supplied in the question

Comment: So wanted to know what changes I can make to the code presented above (or if there is some other way) to move the buttons along